# Matrices, quaternion and angle

Tags: c#, matrix, quaternions

I have 2 matrices. Matrix A and Matrix B which is a 'matrix A rotated by some angle around some axis' (quaternion?).  So: B = A.Transform (quaternion).
now when I know B and A, and maybe axis, how do I find the angle of that quaternion?

Sorry for bad text, I'm on a German keyboard and I'm not German...

Comment: For your keyboard, have you tried using `Alt+Space`? That will switch your keyboard to another language layout.

Comment: I did. But still some mappings are incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have **B** = **A** x **T**

therefore **A**<sup>-1</sup> x **B** = **T**

So take the matrix inverse of **A** and multiply that by **B** to get the Transform matrix.

Then extract the quaternion, (or Euler angles, if you would prefer), using say http://www.cg.info.hiroshima-cu.ac.jp/~miyazaki/knowledge/teche52.html

Comment: Thanks, you saved my life. I converted result to System.Windows.Media.Media3D Qiaternion. Now I read Angle property from object. But I'm not sure, it will give me angle in range 0..180deg or 0..360deg?

Comment: I'm not sure either, but you can fix it up, e.g.
    angle = angle < 0.0 ? angle + 360 : angle;  // to make it > 0